# Collapsing margins after a page break in print CSS

Tags: html, css, print-css, weasyprint

I would like page breaks to occur immediately before an `<h2>`.  An `<h2>` has a top margin on it to separate it from the content before it, but I do not want the margin to appear if it immediately follows a page break, and that is the part I am struggling with.

Right now my CSS looks like this:

```
h2 {
    margin: 2rem 0 0.5rem 0;
}

@media print {
    * {
        page-break-before: avoid;
    }
    h2 {
        page-break-before: auto;
    }
}
```

Margins and page breaks seem to be one of the things that has changed from version to version of CSS.  At one time (CSS 2.0?) the margin for the top element of a page seems to have collapsed with the page's margin, but that's no longer the case.

I am using WeasyPrint under FreeBSD, if that is relevant.  I'm styling HTML generated from markdown, so adding `<section>` or `<div>` tags is awkward at best.